# Refresh "Button" that only refreshes components if their props have changed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm pretty new to React and Redux and I've been setting my environment in the past week.

I was wondering if their was such a thing as a refresh button that doesn't refresh the whole page but just the components containing the props that have changed in the store.

Example :

- User_1 changes the store.
- User_2 clicks a refresh button on his page (container).
- The components containing props that have been modified are refreshed for User_2.

The perfect situation would be if User_2's interface components would refresh as soon as User_2 does the action, but I don't think it's possible yet. (If it is, please mention it)

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
If you use GraphQl, it's worth looking into their "***subscription***" solution.

Comment: You basically want a websocket that connects and updates the store, likely through a middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your two user's are on different computers, then the store is not shared between them.  Changes made to one user's store are not going to impact the store of a second user.

It sounds like what you really want is websockets.  But this would be something you need to manage with the server-side of your application first, and which react/redux would merely consume.

In general, components will always *instantly* update when their props change.  If a component didn't update, then it's props are still the same.

Comment: Following up on your web sockets solution. Would both users' stores always be connected or would I need to trigger an action to make them communicate?

Comment: Or would the user_1's store make changes on the API and then the user_2's store would need to obtain these new values and then refresh its components?

Comment: Websockets are an entirely separate piece of technology.  How you choose to integrate those into a react/redux front end is entirely up to you.